# Rails way for different views of a resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Let us assume we have two resources: auctions and bids, and that an auction has many bids possibly modeled as nested resources. There are two possible collections of bids: the collection of all bids in the rails application and the collection of bids associated with a particular auction. If the user wants to access both of these collections, how would we model this in the controllers?

One possible solution is to construct two routes (auctions/:auction_id/bids and bids/) that point to the BidsController#index action and branch according to the presence of params[:auction_id]. One can imagine that the situation worsens if a bid also belongs to a user, thus creating another conditional on our BidsController checking for params[:user_id] to return the collection of bids associated to a given user. What is the rails way of dealing with this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The out of the box solution for dealing with nested resources is to handle it in child resource controller:

```
Sampleapp::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :bids

  resources :users do
    resources :bids # creates routes to BidsController
  end

  resources :auctions do
    resources :bids # creates routes to BidsController
  end
end

class BidsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_bids, only: [:index]
  before_action :set_bid, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]

  def index
  end

  # ... new, create, edit, update, destroy   

  def set_bid
    # when finding a singular resources we don't have to give a damn if it is nested
    @bid = Bids.find(params[:id])
  end

  def set_bids
    @bids = Bids.includes(:user, :auction)
    if params.has_key?(:user_id)
      @bids.where(user_id: params[:user_id])
    elsif params.has_key?(:auction_id)
      @bids.where(auction_id: params[:auction_id])
    end
    @bids.all
  end
end
```

The advantage here is that you get the full CRUD functionality with very little code duplication.

You could however quite simply override the index routes if you want to have different view templates, or do different sorting etc.

```
Sampleapp::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :bids

  resources :users do
    member do
      get :bids, to: 'users#bids', :bids_per
    end
    resources :bids, except: [:index]
  end

  resources :auctions do
    member do
      get :bids, to: 'auction#bids', as: :bids_per
    end
    resources :bids, except: [:index]
  end

end
```

Another solution would be creating a `AuctionsBidsController` and defining the route as such:

```
resources :auctions do
  resources :bids, only: [:index], controller: 'AuctionsBids'
  resources :bids, except: [:index]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily have to involve the bids controller every time you want to display a list of bids.  For example, if I were setting up this scenario and wanted to display a list of bids related to a particular auction, I would handle that in the auctions controller, not the bids controller, like so:

```
class AuctionsController < ApplicationController
...
def show
  @auction = Auction.find(params[:id])
  @bids = @auction.bids #assuming the bids belong_to your Auction model
end
```

Then, somewhere in the view app/views/auctions/show.html.erb you can list the bids using the same partial you use in your bids index:

```
<ul>
  <%= render partial: 'bids/bid', collection: @bids %>
</ul>
```

This is just one way to handle the situation.  You could do the same thing with your User model or any other model in your application.  The point is that you don't have to involve a model's specific controller every time you want that model to appear in a view.